# Bootstrap 2 - Span12 wont allow a left margin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple app set up.  Here is the markup:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12" style="height: 25px; background: green;"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add a `4px` margin to the left and the right of my green div.  I add `margin-left: 4px` and everything looks great.  When I try to do the same thing on the right side `margin-right: 4px;`, it does not work.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you've missing, but here is a fiddle with what you need : 
http://bootply.com/102568

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12" style="height: 25px; background: green; padding: 0px 4px 0px 4px">
    my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - my content - 
  </div>
</div>
```

Tested on chromium, i see the padding on left and right...

Comment: I just did the same thing and everything looks like I would expect.  I don't know what is going on with this project.